# How to target iframe in original top window from children popup windows?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have html document with iframe in it, lets call it window "A".

Inside of this iframe I have a link that opens popup window with window.open(..), lets call it window "B".

From this popup window I open yet another popup window with window.open(..), lets call it window "C".

Now from window "C" i want to change location of iframe in window "A". how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the frames are from the same domain, and assuming no one is messing around with the `opener` property, you can do this by looking at the `opener` property of the `window`.

```
function rootWindow(win){
    while(win.opener instanceof Window){
        win = win.opener
    }
    return win;
}
```